# Redirect language permanently

Tags: .htaccess

I need to delete Spanish language on a website and redirect all pages to the English version of the site. Preferrably redirect each page to the associated page in the English version (Pages are associated in the Joomla Menu).

mydomain.com/es/quienes needs to go ot mydomain.com/about
or
mydomain.com/es and mydomain.com/es/quienes need to go to: mydomain.com

Now I know I could redirect them one by one using Redirect 301 rules but is there an easier way using RewriteCond and RewriteRule

Thanks

Comment: What’s easier than a redirect rule? Things like this is _literally_ their purpose. Request comes to server, server redirects user.

Comment: Your web server knows nothing about any “associated” English pages on that level, so you could only hard-code it. If you want any automatism, then you will have to implement this _in_ Joomla, only that system knows about this association of the Spanish pages with their English counterparts.

Comment: Ok so what rule would I put if all that starts with mydomain.com/es/xyz gets redirected to the homepage of the english version which would be mydomain.com

Comment: @user2439629 Please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla-related questions there.